SwiftUI Using dynamic nested dictionary values as Binding Values - issues with wrapping
The gist of the issue is that I want to filter a list of items based on various criteria from the list itself. For example, I have a list of food items, and I want to filter based on the possible values from this list:


To help accomplish this, I have nested class/structs:
class Filters {
    // Other types of filters, like date, etc.
    var listFilters: [String:ListFilter] = [:]
}

struct ListFilter {
    var name: String
    var items: [String: FilterShowAndOn]
}

struct FilterShowAndOn {
    var showFilter: Bool
    var filterOn: Bool
}


For example, some filters I initialize are:
func initFilters() -> Filters{
    let filters = Filters()
    
    filters.listFilters["Type"] = ListFilter(name: "Type", items:
                                                ["Vegetable": FilterShowAndOn(showFilter: true, filterOn: true),
                                                 "Fruit":FilterShowAndOn(showFilter: true, filterOn: true)])
    
    filters.listFilters["Color"] = ListFilter(name: "Color", items:
                                                ["Red": FilterShowAndOn(showFilter: true, filterOn: true),
                                                 "Green":FilterShowAndOn(showFilter: true, filterOn: true),
                                                 "Red":FilterShowAndOn(showFilter: true, filterOn: true)])
    
    return filters
}

In the filters sheet, I want to show these and use the filterOn bool for the toggles
struct FiltersView: View {
    @Binding var filters: Filters
    
    var body: some View {
        Section("Type"){
            ForEach(filters.listFilters["Type"]!.items.keys.sorted(), id:\.self){ key in
                Toggle(key, isOn: $filters.listFilters["Type"].items[key].filterOn)
            }
        }
    }
}

But I get errors no matter how I try to wrap/unwrap. Is there any way to make this work?

I've tried wrapping/unwrapping but I only get more errors. I'm very new to swift so don't really know what's going on :(

A dictionary is probably a poor choice, but the error message is telling you what the problem is. listFilters["Type"] returns an optional. As far as the compiler is concerned there may or may not be a value in the dictionary with the key "Type". Also structs won't really work for you because they are immutable

I tried switching to classes, same error; then I tried force unwrapping and it says "Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Binding<_>'". Thoughts on what I could use instead of a dictionary to keep things dynamic? Even if I remove the top-level dictionary for listFilters, the items themselves are dynamic; should I use arrays instead?

Yes, you want arrays. I am working through a solution.

This is my solution using arrays - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/85a5e942768b26029f5c9df98f7b425a

That makes a lot of sense! There's no need for the dictionary; the backend doesn't need to match the frontend, so of course the list with the types makes things much easier. Thanks so much - not only for the solution, but also for showing me some good practices (given how new I am to swift, my code is messy and this really helps get a better idea of how to organize it.) Please feel free to post as an answer so I can check it as correct!
